# How exactly i can access my Astral body in meditation?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, lay-buddhism, buddha

Lord Buddha have access to unlimited knowledge, This information can be found in old Indian scriptures as well, that human body is capable to visiting to another planets with his/her Astral body (Suksham Sharir).

Is there some particular way or do i need Guru for this particular thing ?
Many Buddhist monk don't teach this, i am aware that Lord buddha himself have denied not to show any super powers.

These Siddhi's (powers) may lead to Ego, But going in universe have always been an interesting thing for anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to say that their is no meaning to aim for developing Siddhi. Doing so demonstrate that you are on the wrong way and therefore it will take much more time to reach them. Siddhi are fruits on the path.

Doing things with Astral body is possible for anyone, since it is just a part of yourself. The point is to get a part big enough of your conscience to go with it.

This as nothing to do with meditation or Buddhism. 
To have a good mediation it is more important to be here and now, well centered, and therefore with your astral body inside. Nowadays, most of the person have their astral body somewhere else (high astral, low, or around).

Comment: Could you expand on the last part? The astral body inside? Seems to me like the physical body is inside the more subtle bodies (including the astral)

Comment: In addition to otaku's reply, the abilities to 'project' on the higher planes are no "Siddhis' per-se. No super powers either.

Comment: @Oyiwai The Astral body is the most mobile subtle body we have (causal one can move as well but not others). It does go out when you sleep, and most of the people are actually having it out of their physical body.  And I totally agree to disinguish Siddhis and astral travel.

Answer (score 1):

The Visuddhimagga covers the topic of paranormal powers quite extensively.  A prerequisite for any, however, is a mastery of the rupa and arupa jhanas. You've got a long road ahead of you with that!  ;-)  And figure that by the time you get there, you'll probably have lost interest in siddhis anyway.